# Rename an uwp app which is published in ms store

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, publishing

I have successfully published an app in ms store. After then I was trying to update this app Microsoft returns an issue "The app name does not accurately represent the app"
So I decided to change the name of app by doing below steps.

1. Under the Application UI under the Package.appxmanifest I have changed the "Display Name" with new app name
2. Reserved a new name using Microsoft account
3. Tried to create a package using this new reserved name

But when creating package it shows an error

> "The DisplayName element of the Properties element must have the App
>   name value:new app name"

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/manage-app-names#rename-an-app-that-has-already-been-published

Comment: yes,shows same issue

Comment: Do you re-associate your project with Store and update `package.xml` then update the `Display Name`? If not, you might not be able to generate the package correctly.

Comment: yes I have tried as you mentioned. Shows same package error

Answer (score 1):

Pratyay's comment worked as an answer for me.

The new app name had already been reserved and assigned, but I was getting this error when trying to build a new package with the new name.

```
Package.appxmanifest(6,6): error APPX1607: The DisplayName element of the Properties element must have the App name value: 'RESERVEDNAME1;RESERVEDNAME2'. [C:\agent\_work\75\s\Solution\Project\Project.csproj]
```

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/manage-app-names#rename-an-app-that-has-already-been-published) pointed out that the `Package.StoreAssociation.xml` file needed to be updated first. I deleted the existing file and re-associated it with the Store by right-clicking the project -> `Publish` -> `Associate App with the Store...`. I had to check the box `Include app names that already have packages`. Then I followed the prompts, submitted the new package to the store, and I was good to go.